# How to add .jar as a library and authenticate Twitter with OAuth

Tags: twitter, android-studio, jar, twitter-oauth

So I'm making an app that has access to reading tweets from http://www.api.twitter.com. So for authentication, I downloaded the unofficial twitter api, Twitter4j. I downloaded it as a zip then converted it to a jar file. I made a libs folder in the project section in android studio and added it in and right clicked >> add as library. The thing is when I write import twitter4j.etc etc in MainActivity , it cannot "resolve" twitter4j. What am I doing wrong? Is this the right way to authenticate OAuth with Twitter? How do I make android studio recognize this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add libraries this way also.

**Project Structure -> Dependencies -> Library Dependency( Add button from top right corner) -> Search your Libraries(Here Twitter) -> select required library -> Click Ok**

After Sync you can use that library

Answer (score 0):

add it under `*appName*/app/lib` and hit **synchronize**